# rails apply where if variable is not nil else apply all - nicer way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

How to optimize/refactor this rails code,

I want to apply where condition to the Country and the City if the co is not nil, if its nil, then apply all.

```
  def pre(co = nil,ci = nil)

    cond1 =  co.nil? ? "all" : "where(:id => co)"
    cond2 =  ci.nil? ? "all" : "where(:id => ci)"

    @countries = Country.send(cond1).order(:name).map{|i| [i.name,i.id]}  
    @cities = City.send(cond2).order(:name).map{|i| [i.name,i.id]}  

  end
```

**Is it a nice way or is there a nicer way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@countries = Country.where(co.nil? || {:id => co}).order(:name).map{|i| [i.name,i.id]}  
@cities = City.where(ci.nil? || {:id => ci}).order(:name).map{|i| [i.name,i.id]}
```

Comment: You can write it nicer with `where(co.nil? || {:id => co})`

Comment: I think this code is not better that the example above. There is the same duplication. Putting everything in one line is not an improvement. Readability is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
@country = Country
@city = City

if co.blank?
@country = @country.where(:id => co)
end

if ci.blank?
@city = @city.where(:id => ci)
end

@countries = @country.order(:name).all.map{|i| [i.name,i.id]}  
@cities = @city.order(:name).all.map{|i| [i.name,i.id]}
```

Comment: Can you tell what efficiency this brings?

Comment: It is better to call the functions directly then calling it indirectly by send and also this looks like a Rails way.

Answer (score 0):

You would think about something like this.

```
def pre(co = nil, ci = nil)
  @countries = scopify(Country, co)
  @cities    = scopify(City, ci)
end

def scopify(model_or_scope, attribute)
  scope = model_or_scope.scoped
  scope = scope.where(:id => attribute) if attribute.present?
  scope.order(:name).map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
end
```